# Kendoui Scheduler Year View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using the Kendoui Scheduler (beta) that currently only supports day, week, month, agenda. Is there a way to add 'year' view? Potentially through config or an additional template? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For yearly view have to manage your own way.

Comment: I'm looking the same thing but Quarter view. It is hard to find example to display more than one month. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Kendoui now offers a timeline view that you can customize by overriding the calculateDateRange function, 
Have a look at
[this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/timeline-year-view)